# adding a serial port vivado/ISE microzed board-Xilinx

Tags: fpga, device-tree, xilinx-ise, vivado, zynq

I am running xillinux on my microzed board. I need to define a new serial port on the board using vivado. I was able to add this to the IP core and the device is ready. But,how do I make this port visible on ubuntu (xillinux) like ttyPS0. DO I need to add this port to the device tree and generate the dtb file and boot.bin file ? IF so, how do I modify the device tree ?

1.) Now again, instead of vivado if I use ISE, then would I be able to update the device tree source file in the ISE software itself and generate the device tree .dtb file ? If so, where can I find and edit this dts file ?

2.) And for building the new boot.bin file in ISE, I can use http://xillybus.com/downloads/u-boot...ux-1.3.elf.zip for the microzed or can I use the bin file for microzed from xillybus.com/downloads/xillin...rozed-1.3c.zip ?

3.) Even after using the ISE and creating the new .dtb (if possible in ISE), do I have to edit dtc files on the xillinux OS in the micozed board ?

4.) If I need to follow step 3 above to get everything working, based on this link, http://xillybus.com/tutorials/device-tree-zynq-1

I can go only upto to cd /usr/src/kernels/3.12.0-xillinux-1.3/scripts/dtc/

If I type cd /dtc again, it says dtc not a directory.

How do I access the device tree script and add the address mapping to the bus in the peripheral section ?
How do I compile this and make the new device tree start on every boot ?

Comment: @rhobincu Can you please help me on this ? Especially the device tree on how to access it in ISE, compile and generate dtb.

Answer (score 0):

> I can go only upto to cd
>   /usr/src/kernels/3.12.0-xillinux-1.3/scripts/dtc/
>
> If I type cd /dtc again, it says dtc not a directory.

Sure, `/usr/src/kernels/3.12.0-xillinux-1.3/scripts/dtc/dtc` is a binary executable. It has been compiled with the Linux kernel. It is the Device Tree Compiler (thus its name) that turns a Device Tree Source `foo.dts` into a binary Device Tree Blob `foo.dtb`. The DTS is a text file describing the available hardware and how to access it. The DTB is the same information but in a binary format that the Linux kernel parses at boot time to discover the hardware it is running on and to attach software drivers to the hardware peripherals (among other things).

So, to use the `dtc` just add `/usr/src/kernels/3.12.0-xillinux-1.3/scripts/dtc` to your path and use it:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/src/kernels/3.12.0-xillinux-1.3/scripts/dtc
$ dtc -I dts -O dtb -o foo.dtb foo.dts
```